# Is positive energy trap possible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, traps, positive-energy

Positive energy plane has major positive-dominant trait. Its positive effects are granting fast healing 5 ability and 5 temporary HP per round for fully healed heroes. On the other hand, failed DC 15 fortitude save causes hero to become blind for 10 rounds. What's more, if hero has those temporary HP, failed DC 20 fortitude save causes hero to spontaneously explode.

**Can this mechanism be used in a trap?**

For example, can I disguise the trap as pool of healing that heals heroes that have entered it (as usual), but if they stay too long they may explode as on positive energy plane?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Planar Handbook, p. 131, has a LA+5 template called *Vivacious*.

A Vivacious creature, among other bonuses, gains the *Positive Energy Aura* Supernatural Ability:

> Any living creature within 10 feet of a vivacious creature gains 1 hit point per round due to  the  aura  of  positive  energy  surrounding  it.  Creatures that exceed their full normal hit points from this effect need  to  make  Fortitude saves as if in a positive-dominant environment. [...]

It therefore seems quite simple to build such a "trap": just capture a Vivacious Creature and trap it in your Fountain of Rejuvenation. Any who comes within 10 ft. of the creature will be subject to the positive-dominant environment effects.

Bonus point: the players may decide, if they realize the creature is there against its will, to free it.

Comment: I like this one, it's consistent with official material and even more interesting than I thought. If the heroes will be trapped in small room with unconscious vivacious creature, the easiest way to not explode will be to kill it, but DM may present it as moral dilemma for good heroes.

Answer (score 5):

**This is possible, but not necessarily how you'd expect.**

You can easily make a magical trap that has this effect via GM fiat. I imagine you already knew that, though. Assuming, therefore, that you want to use the magical trap rules for this:

1. First, You could either find a positive energy spell that includes the 'explode when too healthy' rule in its text. Note that most spells that use positive energy don't.
2. You could make a magical trap that sends creatures to the positive energy plane. Plane Shift and Gate are the classics, but there are others. (Personally, I'd build a length of dungeon corridor on the Positive Energy Plane with a permanent *gate* to the Prime Material Plane at either end. If you build the corridor a little smaller than the gates, your players might not even realise they're moving between planes - and will stay in the 'healing zone' of their own free will, little realising that they're healing to their deaths! Bwahahahaha!)

Comment: Permanent gate spell is nice idea, but if hero is transported to Positive Energy Plane, he/she may be blinded, so the players will know that something is up.

Comment: @dzielins42 Oh, right - I'd forgotten that 3.5rd edition's Positive blinds people. Oh, well - I don't imagine it'll cause too many problems; It wouldn't be the first time a dungeon contained a feature that both helps and hinders the party.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. But be careful of this, its **really** easily abused. I had a 3.5 party that was going through a positive energy plane adventure and we went and bought some items to bump fort saves and camped for a week or so in order to get a ridiculous amount of bonus HP. I mean, 1 hr of 5 HP/rnd is 3600/6*5 = 3,000 temporary HP. Spend a week in there and...yeah...

Comment: I would note that on a roll of 1 a Fortitude save fails no matter the bonus, unless special abilities (such as the Steadfast Determination feat). There are mechanisms to re-roll 1s, but at 1 roll/round (and thus 600 rolls/hour), you are looking at an average of 30 rolls of 1... It seems quite difficult for *all* characters to exploit this (a Con-based character could, however).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is simple. There are a number of effects in third edition which alter local planar characteristics to match that of another plane. Provide the location in question with the desired effect so that the inside "is" the positive plane.

One empowers an acorn so that a certain radius around it is considered to be under the tree it comes from. Handy due to extended, but still limited time duration.

Another focuses on a creature, so that the planar surroundings match the creature's native plane. Again of limited duration.

All of these effects can be transferred into architecture, which allows you to alter the size and duration characteristics of the positive energy plane effect.

There are more.

Comment: (The spell [*acorn of far travel*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fw/20040710a) doesn't affect an area but the carrier: "As long as you carry the acorn (and as long as the acorn is not stored in an extradimensional space like a *bag of holding*), you are considered to be standing under that oak tree's canopy (and thus within an area of forested terrain).")

Comment: There are clever ways to exploit this effect such that it would affect an area with its effect. Thus this becomes a sneaky but effective way of accomplishing the request.

Comment: Or to affect multiple "carriers", now that I think of it.

Comment: Why not share these ways as part of your answer?

Comment: Am I being too specific? It seemed to me the OP was only asking if it was possible, not asking a how-to question.....

Comment: Brief research of acorn of far travel shows that the spell "must be cast upon an acorn that is still attached to a living oak tree". As far as I have researched, positive energy plane does not have oak trees (although it's subject to DM decision).

Comment: If this trap is being prepared with the acorn method, planting such a tree, should one not be able to be found naturally on the plane, would seem a logical step. There are other ways of making the area under the canopy of the tree count as part of the positive energy plane, as well.

Comment: I used to imagine the site as a courtroom where I'd been called to testify as a witness in the question's trial. Then I started imagining the site as university where the dean's begging me to give a guest lecture on the question. Then I started imagining the site as a rowdy coffee house where gamers hang out and a dude comes up to my table and asks me the question as he's heard I was an expert. The site *functions* if it's the courthouse, and it's *interesting* if it's the lecture hall, but it's *fun* if it's the coffee house.

Comment: Heh. I think I'm getting your courtroom effect, mostly. It seems that I get criticized and judged no matter what approach I take to my questions, answers, and comments. I am choosing to view it as constructive and helpful, but one does feel a bit of fatigue at the sheer amount of such responses I'm getting. Newb growing pains I guess.

Comment: I understand, and, you're right, that's totally a thing. If you start imagining readers as opponents, a forum will be much more comfortable. But if you start imagining readers as friendly collaborators who, really, ultimately want the same thing you do—a useful answer or an interesting question—the site holds a lot of opportunity to challenge your own understanding of the hobby.

Comment: With that in mind, reread the question and your answer and ask yourself if this were your question about which you knew nothing (which is why you asked it, after all), would you find your answer useful? Sure, it might *start* you down a path, but is the path is long, twisted, confusing, and dangerous? Then the answer isn't *useful*. Be a friendly guide, not a signpost. (Note that I'm interested in an expanded version of this answer—not so I can pick it apart and prove it doesn't work but because I really do want to see how it works.)

Comment: Hmm. Well, since there is an expression of interest.... I'll see what I can do. It'll have to wait till I'm on my computer. It's a bit tough posting these things via phone. ^^